# Symlinked PNGs work but SVGs don't

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a Magento 1.9 install on a LEMP server.

We're trying to set up different storefronts for different languanges as subfolders eg. /en /it /de etc. with the media and such symlinked.

Everything is working fine (that I can see) except all the SVGs are 404ing.  PNGs in the same folders are working correctly.  Permissions/Owners are identical.  Error logs seem to just show it as a typical 404 with the file location being correct.  I'm at a loss.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sometimes typing the issue out helps your think more about the issue and come up with a solution.  If anybody ends up with a similar issue check your nginx and make sure you have SVG here

```
  location ~* \.(woff|js|css|svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
    expires 7d;
  }
```